# What happens to uninitialized class members in c++?

Tags: c++, class, data-members

What happens to uninitialized class members in c++? If I have to do this, what should I take care of?

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

class Foo {
    int attr1, attr2;   
public:
    Foo ();

Foo::Foo () {   attr1 = 5; }

Foo myThing();
```

Comment: attr2 will contain garbage value

Comment: Why do you have to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What happens to uninitialized class members in c++?

They are default initialized, which in case of fundamental types like `int` means that it will have an indeterminate value.

> what should I take care of?

You should take care to never read an indeterminate value.

Comment: @Taylor You should start a habit of initializing variables when you declare them or in the constructors.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews i already have this habit

Comment: @Taylor:  You need more diligence.  The variable `attr2` is not initialized in your constructor.

Answer (score 2):

They are default-constructed.

For nested classes this means these have to have a constructor that can be called without arguments.

For plain old data members (`int` et. al.) this means they simply stay uninitialized as any other *local* variable would.